# Two column masonry with single gutter

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I have created the following CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmjHy

The idea being to have a two column masonry of boxes that should have 20px of spacing in between them. I have set the `box-sizing` to be `border-box` to ignore the border and inner padding of each item.

However the second column is collapsing under the first... Presumably because the `50%` and the 20px on BOTH boxes (left and right) adding to it.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I've looked at perhaps doing:

`'columnWidth': $('.masonry').width() / 2` and having the `.item` set to `100%` in the CSS but that doesn't seem to work either... perhaps because the gutter is appending to the right column boxes too?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.masonry').masonry({
    'itemSelector': '.item',
    'gutter': 20
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { 

  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.masonry {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.masonry .item {
  width:  50%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `width:  calc(50% - 10px);` would work, but that's not supported in all browsers yet :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the following to your `$(document).ready`

```
  $(window).on("resize load", function() {
    var desired_width = $(".masonry").width()/2 - 10
    $('.masonry .item').css("width", desired_width)
  })
```

It should give the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a solution of a two-column masonry, with a gutter of 30px. It still appends it to both columns but adding a `overflow:hidden` on the grid element allows the unwanted right gutter to be obscured.

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/natbatwat/pen/VLJjmy